# How to get text input from user in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, user-interface, prompt

[This is my extension pop-up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ND2gK.png).

I want to create an input field when users click on any keywords there, allowing them to edit the descriptions, maybe a pop-up like prompt(). Do you guys know any way to create something like that?

Thanks in advance,

(sorry for my very bad english)

Comment: uh... how bout `prompt()` ...or an HTML input.. what is the problem with using the normal methods?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21243599/alternative-to-javascripts-prompt-for-google-chrome-web-app
In this topic he said we cant use prompt in an chrome extension. however, i never make a try though :))

Comment: ok, so what's wrong with the answer on that page? use an html input.. ?

Comment: omg, i'm so dumb. i dont even read the answer in that link :)) srr for making u so confused :))